# Mellanox and Infiniband latency

Tags: infiniband

I have two hosts with Voltaire HCA500Ex-D (MT25408 ConnectX Mellanox) 10Gbit cards connected to a Cisco SFS7000d IB switch via CX4 3m cables.

I'm really concerned about latency which is higher than on 1Gbit ethernet connection using same hosts.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ibping -G 0x0008f104039a5589
Pong from host-a.(none) (Lid 3): time 0.238 ms
Pong from host-a.(none) (Lid 3): time 0.291 ms
Pong from host-a.(none) (Lid 3): time 0.320 ms
Pong from host-a.(none) (Lid 3): time 0.290 ms
Pong from host-a.(none) (Lid 3): time 0.335 ms
Pong from host-a.(none) (Lid 3): time 0.281 ms
```

Most people are getting 0.040ms - 0.050ms using the same IB cards.

Cisco IB Switch and cards are running latest firmware.

I've tried connecting two hosts back-to-back eliminating the switch but latency is still 0.200ms+

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Downloading and installing a recent version of the [Open Fabrics Enterprise Distribution(OFED)](http://downloads.openfabrics.org/OFED/) will give you access to a variety of tools, including `ibdiagnet` as well as several other IB performance testing and tuning tools.  In addition to these tools it will give you the option to install and configure openibd and OpenSM, and open source subnet manager.

Based on the documentation, the

> Cisco SFS7000d IB switch

you mentioned is running its own onboard IB subnetmanager.  It would be beneficial to either

1. Disable the subnet manager on the switch and configure OpenSM on one of the servers
2. Verify that the configuration of the subnet manager on the switch is appropriate for your network

In addition to taking these steps there are a number of other tests that can effectively measure latency and bandwidth over infiniband.  Using a Message Passing Interface(MPI) implementation (OpenMPI, or a proprietary version) ping-pong benchmark test.  Here is a good example of [setting up and configuring an MPI ping-pong test with OpenMPI over IB](http://pkg-ofed.alioth.debian.org/howto/infiniband-howto-6.html).

Answer (score 0):

Sometime higher then expected latency depends on bad power saving behavior.

Try to disable any power management options in both the BIOS and the card drivers in both hosts, then repeat you ping test with direct server connection.

Does it change something?